# Считывание звука с микрофона в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Как мне считывать звук с микрофона и визуализировать, например, на шкале с децибелами? Какой это виджет? Как это реализовать?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtmultimedia-audiorecorder-example.html

Comment: с визуализацией веселее, вам понадобиться что-то типа быстрых преобразований фурье для потока данных с микрофона

Comment: Ну а как тогда считывать?